# Проблема с установкой ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

Возникает проблема при установке ubuntu 18.04.Приобрел ноутбук lenovo ideapad 330 -15ich.
Серия процессора

Intel® Core™ i5 (8 поколение)

Модель процессора 8300H

Kоличество ядер 4

Базовая частота процессора 2.3 ГГц

Тип памяти DDR4

Объем ОЗУ 8 Гб

Частота памяти 2400 MHz

Объем жесткого диска HDD 1 тб

Тип видеокарты дискретная

Производитель видеокарты NVIDIA

Модель видеокарты GeForce GTX1050

Объем видеопамяти 2 Гб
Установка с флешки, все как обычно, пишет что установка завершена и необходимо перезагрузить, начинаю перезагрузить и появляется черный экран и на этом все...пол часа  час и ничего. Диск на разделы разбил без swap. Подскажите кто знает.Спасибо.

Comment: Если пришли на убунту с винды - проверьте в настройках bios/uefi тип `secure boot`'a. Должен быть `Other OS` вместо `Windows`. Если выбора нет, но `secure boot` включен - попробуйте выключить его.

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к вопросу, у меня точно такой же баг бывает примерно 2-3 раза в месяц. В моём случае лечится обычной перезагрузкой. Со второй попытки всегда загружается. Никаких ошибок в логах при этом нигде нет (проверял при помощи gnome-logs).

Comment: При 8 Гиг ОЗУ swap уже и не нужен (хотя всё рано есть армия поклонников данного раздела)

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать переключиться на вторую консоль и там уже смотреть что да как.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> это включить вторую консоль.
Если переключится, то залогиниться и запустить иксы.